Radon measure, passage to limit in BV space
Let $ \Omega $ be a bounded domain of $ \mathbb{R}^N,\ N \geq 2 $ and  $ (u_n)_n $ a bounded sequence of $ W^{1,p_n}( \Omega), $ where $ p_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}, n =1,2,\ldots. $ We also assume that $ (u_n)_n $ is bounded in $ L^{\infty}( \Omega)$. Let $ u \in BV( \Omega) \cap L^{\infty}( \Omega) $ be such that $ u_n(x) \to u(x) $ a.e. $ x \in \Omega $ and $ \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_1} \to \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} $ weakly* as measures, i.e.
$$
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_1} \varphi dx \to \int_{\Omega} \varphi d \mu_1,\quad \forall\varphi \in C_b( \Omega), $$
where $ \mu_1 $ is the regular measure that represents the Radon measure $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}. $ My question is: is it true that
$$
\int_{\Omega} u_n \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_1} \varphi dx \to \int_{\Omega} u \varphi d \mu_1,\ \forall\ \varphi \in C_c^{\infty}( \Omega)?\label{1}\tag{$***$} $$
Personally, I tried to write:
$$ 
\int_{\Omega} u_n \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_1} \varphi dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial u_n^2}{\partial x_1} \varphi dx = - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} u_n^2 \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_1} dx \to - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} u^2 \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_1} dx, 
$$
where we used the Lebesgue's odminated convergence theorem. Now, it remains to show that $ \frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x_1} = 2 u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} $ which is known in Sobolev space but not in BV space. Maybe there is another way to show \eqref{1}.

This is a consequence of a standard result on $\text{BV}$-functions, first proved by Aizik Isaakovich Vol'pert in the $C^1$ case and then by Ambrosio and Dal Maso in the $C^{0,1}$ case: the result is precisely the following one
Theorem (simplified statement of [1], §2, theorem 2.1., pp. 696-700). Let $u\in\operatorname{BV}(\Omega)$ were $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\Bbb R^n$, and let $f\in C^{0,1}$: then $f(u)(x)=f\circ u(x)\in\operatorname{BV}(\Omega)$.
As a corollary, since $f(x)=x^2$ is $C^2$ and thus also Lipschitz, we have that $u\in\operatorname{BV}(\Omega)$ implies $u^2\in\operatorname{BV}(\Omega)$, thus
$$
\frac{\partial u^2(x)}{\partial x_i} = u(x) \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_i} \quad\forall i =1, \ldots, n
$$
are well defined Radon measures so all the integrals shown in the question are all well defined and meaningful.
References
[1] Luigi Ambrosio and Gianni Dal Maso, "A general chain rule for distributional derivatives" (English), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 108, No. 3, 691-702 (1990), MR969514, Zbl 0685.49027.
[2] Aizik Isaakovich Vol’pert, A. I. "The spaces $\text{BV}$ and quasilinear equations" (English. Russian original) Math. USSR, Sb. 2(1967), 225-267 (1968); translation from Mat. Sb., n. Ser. 73(115), 255-302 (1967), MR216338, Zbl 0168.07402.

Thank you for your answer. I know that u^2 \in BV( \Omega). However, I think that the chain formula is valid in the form that I stated only in the case when $ D u $ has no a jump part.

@SemiMath, I'm not sure if it is so. I'm not aware of such kind of limitation on the validity of the chain rule: moreover your formula is a particularisation of the one proved in section 13.4, p. 249 of Vol'pert's paper.

Thank you again.
